# Program to find cuberoot of a number

Tags: python

So I'm a complete beginner (like less than a week) and wrote this code in python. It's supposed to find the cuberoot of a number if the solution is an integer, and approximate it otherwise. It does both instead of just one or the other. I've tried it multiple ways for hours now but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

```
cube=int(input("what number's cube root do you want to find"))
epsilon = 0.01
increment = 0.0001
num_guesses = 0
for guess in range(cube+1):
if guess**3 == cube:
    guess += 1
    print (guess)
else:
guess1 = 0.0
    while abs(guess1**3 - cube) >= epsilon:
        guess1 += increment
        num_guesses += 1
        print('num_guesses =', num_guesses) 

    else:
        print(guess1)
```

Comment: What do you mean "it does both"? Show your expected output vs what it's actually outputting.

Comment: It looks like your indentation in the post is off - please fix it as in Python it is critical

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your indentation. Everything in your "else" statement needs to be indented to show that it is inside the "else" statement. You also have a few logical errors in your code. If you have found a number that, when cubed, is the desired number, you should print that number, not that number plus 1. And if you've found the solution, your program should stop there.

```
for guess in range(cube+1):
    if guess**3 == cube:
        print (guess)
        return
guess1 = 0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working solution:

```
cube=int(input("what number's cube root do you want to find: "))
epsilon = 0.01
increment = 0.0001
num_guesses = 0
int_result_found = False
for guess in range(cube+1):
    if guess**3 == cube:
        print guess
        int_result_found = True
        break

if not int_result_found:
    guess1 = 0.0
    while abs(guess1**3 - cube) >= epsilon:
        guess1 += increment
        num_guesses += 1
        #print 'num_guesses =', num_guesses 

    print(guess1)
```

As Erik said, there were some errors in your code. Key point is to stop after you've found integer solution, I've used boolean flag `int_result_found` for that.

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems with you code is indenting. Python requires specific spacing in order to work properly.

The easiest way to avoid getting both answers is to create a boolean variable (I used "found_answer") to check if it is necessary to run the second code.

I've fixed you code, modifying it as little as possible:

```
cube=int(input("what number's cube root do you want to find"))
found_answer = False

for guess in range(cube+1):
    if guess**3 == cube:
        print ("integer answer:", guess)
        found_answer = True

if found_answer == False:
    epsilon = 0.01
    increment = 0.0001
    num_guesses = 0
    guess1 = 0.0
    while abs(guess1**3 - cube) >= epsilon:
        guess1 += increment
        num_guesses += 1
        print('num_guesses =', num_guesses)
    print("approximate answer:", guess1)
```

Answer (score 0):

when it comes to "guess**3 == cube", I think you need to "break"

try this:

```
cube=int(input("what number's cube root do you want to find"))

epsilon = 0.01
increment = 0.0001

for i in range(cube + 1):
    if i**3 == cube:
        # break the loop
        break 
    elif (i+1)**3 > cube > i**3:  # this is to reduce unnecessary calculations
        while (abs(i**3 - cube) >= epsilon):
            i += increment
        break
print(i)
```

and I'd like to make it a func:

```
cube=int(input("what number's cube root do you want to find"))

epsilon = 0.01
increment = 0.0001

def cuberoot(cube):
    for i in range(cube + 1):
        if i**3 == cube:
            break
        elif (i+1)**3 > cube > i**3:
            while (abs(i**3 - cube) >= epsilon):
                i += increment
            break
    return i

print(cuberoot(cube))
```

and what is more easy:

```
def cuberoot(cube):
    return cube**(1/3)
```

Answer (score 0):

For your interest, here is a much more efficient solver:

```
# target function: y = x**3
def cube(x):
    return x * x * x

def diff(f, epsilon = 0.001):
    """
    Given function f, return a numeric approximation function for f'(x)
    """
    def df(x):
        return (f(x + epsilon) - f(x)) / epsilon
    return df

def newton_solver(target_y, f, df = None, start_x = None, epsilon = 0.001, max_reps = 40):
    """
    Newton Raphson approximation

    Given real target_y and function f,
      return real x such that f(x) = target_y +/- epsilon
    """
    # if no differential function is provided, use a numeric approximation
    if df is None:
        df = diff(f)
    # if no starting point is given, guess f(x) ='= x
    if start_x is None:
        x = target_y
    else:
        x = start_x
    for _ in range(max_reps):
        y = f(x)
        err = y - target_y
        if abs(err) < epsilon:
            # close enough
            return x
        else:
            # project the tangent to find a closer approximation
            x -= err / (df(x) or epsilon)
    # no answer found, bail out
    raise ValueError("max_reps exceeded, no solution found")

def main():
    y = int(input("What integer do you want to find the cube root of? "))

    # find x such that y == x**3
    approx_x = newton_solver(y, cube)

    # round to the nearest integer
    int_x = round(approx_x)
    if cube(int_x) == y:
        print("The exact cube root of {} is {}.".format(y, int_x))
    else:
        print("The cube root of {} is approximately {}.".format(y, approx_x))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```